# Call specific functions with Websockets?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I'm trying to deploy an app with Heroku but I guess they don't allow use of Socket.IO so I have to use basic WebSockets. How do I send data to specific functions e.g.

With sockets it would be:

```
// Server
socket.on('testFunction', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

// Client
socket.emit('testFunction', 'Hello!');
```

But with Websockets from what I've googled all I can find is

```
// Server
ws.onmessage = function(data) {};

// Client
ws.send('This is a string, what do I do with myself');
```

Any information would be great. Thanks!

Comment: you need to invent our own envelope, json is simplest. make each send need a type and value property, then you connect the dots to an event emiiter, just like socket.io

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) for some documentation and examples.

Here are some rough equivalents to your Socket.IO examples:

```
// Server
ws.onmessage = function(event) {
  var msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
  switch(msg.type) {
    case "testFunction":
      console.log(msg.text);
      break;
  }
};

// Client
ws.send(JSON.stringify({type: "testFunction", text: "Hello!"}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem depends on your server side code.
The way i solved the function calling problem, is by sending my data to server as an object( stringified), containing controller and action properties.
e.g in pseudo code

```
var request = {controller: "users", action: "login", params: {username: "loginuser", password: "333"} };
socket.emit(JSON.stringify( request) );
```

and on server side i get the controller value, and instantiate a new controller based on it...eg new users_controller(), and call the action on that controller with the params sent from emit.
Of course you need to test if controllers and actions exists, handle errors etc.